# How can I raise my Spanish listening skills from high school level to the level where you can understand everyday talks?

Tags: vocabulario

With reading and writing aside, listening and speaking a language is what I am now focusing on.

People are suggesting me to keep listening to soundtracks and maybe download some music.

But I think enriching my vocabulary should be prioritized, since you will not learn words by just listening.

Also, I observed that even the grammar native speakers use in just everyday talking is still a lot more sophisticated that that we use in our class.

Comment: Practicing is the key for mastering anything.

Comment: @El_Mochiq, I can practice listening, but the words they say have to be something I already learned.

Comment: @Doeser you must be have some spanish partner in order to practice every day, even using what's up or any social network......I don't know if this break some rule but this is my skype: yhoyodaqp  best

Comment: @yhoyo, Thanks, but I don't want to creat any trouble for anyone here. Does the partner have to a native speaker? It is hard to find someone like that; most people just don't even bother making friends with someone who wants to talk Spanish with them all the time and isn't even good at it. By the way, if I don't know any words or grammatical conventions I may have to ask them many times.

Comment: @Doeser yes, must be a native speaker... I know tha is really hard to find someone..... that's why I give you my skype... I'm a native speaker :D

Comment: @Doeser *I can practice listening, but the words they say have to be something I already learned.* - actually they do not have to. I'd rather say in case of only listening you'd have to understand *a certain amount* of what is being said. To grab the basic meaning of what speech will be possible without knowing all words. Of course the more words you know, the easier it will be to induce the meaning of words you do not know yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell you that studying (vocabulary, grammar, etc.) is always key. Sooner or later you will reach a level of proficiency enough to understand and be understood with a decent level of fluency. If you stop studying then your vocabulary will become "stagnant" since you'll stick to the words you know, use workarounds, etc. Basically, you'll *make do* with what you got, and that might prevent you from moving further, to a higher levels of proficiency.

One thing that worked well for me was watching movies (using subtitles or not). I used to watch several times movies I loved. I paid attention not only to vocabulary, but to expressions, to how people pronounce words, etc. Sine I knew these movies well I could put more attention in *how* they where saying things (grammar, vocabulary, pronunciation) than in following or understanding the movie.

If you want to improve listening, I would favor movies over songs. Movies might reflect better how people really work. Songs can be tricky. Also, I would pick a "flavor" of Spanish and stick to it. Do you want your pronunciation to resemble that of the people from Spain, or Mexico, Argentina...?

Comment: I think another key is to be familiar with the pronunciation of every word I learned. Right?

Comment: Yes. You'll be amazed how many times people will have no idea of what you mean just because you pronounced a word slightly different from what they are used to hear it. You could be "couldn't they figure it out? What I said sounds similar enough". I don't mean that pronunciation must be prefect in order for others to understand you, but a proper pronunciation could be a more desirable skill than a really wide vocabulary, for example.

Comment: Do you happen to read Él Alquimista or The Alchemist by any chance?

Comment: I'm from Granada, south of Spain, and believe me, after I left it years ago, only people from my city haven't asked me "¿Cómo?", in order to repeat the sentence. Honestly if you have the chance, go to Spain or any country where spanish is the official language.

Comment: @Doeser, I have read "El Alquimista", although it was some time ago. I could not tell you right now if the language used in the book is "advanced" or "beginner" level. If you are currently reading it and there are things you don't understand or things you want to discuss feel free to post a question here about it.

Comment: Telenovelas are another good option to keep up your comprehension skills, if they are available in your area.

Answer (score 3):

Start with shows and songs for kids, then gradually move up from there. Just think about how most of us were raised. We didn't watch documentaries when we were young and then sesame street as adults.

Answer (score 2):

I used to listen to hispanic music, and still do, and I used to try and transcribe the lyrics by ear.  Since Spanish is written as it sounds, with a little practice, it's very easy.  I would look through my dictionary to find the words I heard, proofread them, translate them, and continue on until I could babble along with the song in unison.  I would mimic the dialects and overall the phonetics.  When I was younger I would listen to "El Morro", the Weird Al Yankovich of hispanic music.

**Also, you HAVE to WANT to learn this!**

Motivation is the **#1** factor in learning another language.  You can repeat Rosetta Stone sentences all day long, but without any satisfactory accomplishments or practical application you won't learn a thing.  [Duolingo](http://duolingo.com) offers a much better alternative to Rosetta Stone in my humble opinion; it's also cheaper, free-er even!  It also allows you to communicate with native speakers of your targeted language.

Read a book, listen to music, read the tabloids/newspapers, postcards, whatever.  Take a resource and soak it up for all it's worth.  Wear the pages out, wear your dictionary out.  If you dictionary pages aren't struggling to stay inside and a part of the book, then you aren't practicing enough.  Obsess over every minuscule detail of your corpus resource.

Comment: It allows you to talk ?

Comment: Duolingo? Yeah, as long as you have a microphone you can utilize their voice practice.

Comment: Do you know how much is it for iOS?

Comment: Duolingo is absolutely free, just got there and see.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that only *listening* to songs is not enough. People might say to themselves that "they're learning" when they do such things, while actually your mind is more likely enjoying some entertainment than sharpening language skills with concentration. They can serve as an aide, but not the main means.

One key practice that helped me massively was to find some podcast/video etc., and then read after them *every single day*, **paying attention to every single word, sentence and intonation**. If they have subtitles, you can just use the subtitles. If they don't, better, you'll **write your own subtitle by *scrupulous dictation***, word by word. You can do it for just 30 minutes per day, but the key is persistence. The dictation process alone for a 20-minute video might very well take you a month, don't worry. It's worth every single minute. The key is not variety, but continuity. After you've practiced 5 to 10 videos/podcasts in the span of 3 to 6 months with concentration, you'll find you've almost unknowingly progressed massively in your Spanish skills, both listening and speaking!

Actually I use this skill for every language I learn. It was definitely key to my SAT scores and English fluency as a non-native speaker. The same to my Spanish progress when I was doing an exchange in Chile :)

Answer (score 1):

Is duolingo too easy for you? I find that app very helpful although I'm just a beginner.

Comment: No, if it wasn't for the subscription fee, I will.

Comment: But duolingo is completely free...

Comment: Definite try it then.